# Download Javascript generated XML in IE6

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use Javascript to make IE6 download a file. It'll be created on the fly using Javascript. This file doesn't exist on a webserver. Here's a small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function clicked() {
  var xml = "<data>Just for testing</data>";
  document.open("text/xml", "replace");
  document.write(xml);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="clicked();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of loading the xml in the browser window, I want it to cause IE6 to prompt the user where to download the data to so that it can be saved without them having to use File -> Save as. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE6 you should be able to use [`document.execCommand()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28VS.85%29.aspx) after your `document.write()`:

```
document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'file.xml');
```

This is not part of any standard and will only work in IE flavor browsers.

Comment: This seems to work. Any chance I could prevent the browser from showing the content as well? The back button and refreshing don't reload the original page.

Comment: You could create an invisible or 0-by-0 iframe, and write the xml into that document instead of the main document.

Answer (score 0):

If your data must be generated client side, then you can post it back to the server so that it can be returned as a downloadable file.

Comment: There is no server, this will be running off a share on an Intranet. I'd love to write a Rails app to do this, but it unfortunately isn't an option. I've got to make do with what I have.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible. A web-browser strictly doesn't allow this, as the ability to save files to disk through JavaScript only, would be very dangerous, even if the confirmation popup shows up.

EDIT: Thanks to other answers, I found out (not surprisingly) that this behavior is possible with some versione of IE.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that. What makes it more dangerous than clicking a link and downloading something malicious from a server?

Comment: XSS + user doesn't need to click perhaps

Comment: Agreed, it is a terrible behavior for a browser to allow.  However, IE does allow it through object.execCommand -- I'm not terribly surprised that it's the only browser that does ;)

Comment: With data coming from a server, the browser will tell you about the location of the data.

Comment: This is for an Intranet app at work. I wouldn't subject normal people on the web to such suckiness ;)

Comment: What do you mean "there is" ?

Comment: Luca: Huh? Are you replying to my comment on OrbMan's answer? If so, by there is no server, I meant there is no web server.